# moving files from a .txt list with partial name

Tags: linux, shell, xargs, mv

I'm tring to move a collection of files from one directory to another.

I have a .txt list with PARTIAL name of the files (one per line) I want to move.

Example:

-> file name: 
"00012377000160-52200308419   -20100101-20101231-G-E92F9BA0A0C932C331273FCD845719813F0B617-1-GTOGR-FDS.txt"

-> what I have from the filename in my .txt file:
E92F9BA0A0C932C331273FCD845719813F0B617

It seems simple, I have to:
1- find the files witch names CONTAIN the strings that are stored in my .txt file
2- then move them to the directory

But..... I'm doing something wrong (maybe expansion order ?)....

This is how I'm trying:

```
for PARTNAME in `cat LIST.TXT`; do mv *"$PARTNAME"* /NEWDIR ; done
```

The wildcards * (anyting after or before the PARTIAL file name) is not working.... it´s been considered as part of the file name, instaed

Any help will be apreciated !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply:

```
while read -r PART; do
    mv *"$PART"*.txt /NEWDIR
done < list.txt
```

Also although I don't recommend word splitting, the way to make your code work was just to properly place your $ sign along with the parameter:

```
for PARTNAME in `cat LIST.TXT`; do mv *"$PARTNAME"* /NEWDIR ; done
```

Comment: It worked !!! Thank you !!! BTW, do you know why the same expansion \*"$PART"\*.txt did not work with CAT ??

Comment: Not sure, shouldn't that be `*"PARTNAME"*`? If you're referring to your original command that is. What was the complete command you used?